# n length combinations from two or more digits with repetition limit

Tags: python, combinations

I have the letters a & b and from them I want to take n length combinations of which a and b have limit for repetition.

For example, if n = 7, a = 4 and b = 3, here are possible desired outcome would be starting with 'b':

```
bbbaaaa
bbabaaa
bbaabaa
bbaaaba
bbaaaab
babbaaa
bababaa
babaaba
babaaab
baabbaa
baababa
baabaab
baaabba
baaabab
baaaabb
```

I've looked into a lot of python & c functions, but none do exactly what I'm asking, and I don't know how to alter/use them into doing so.

What I initially thought of was storing all possible combinations and then picking them where a=(length) of them. However, that easily runs into memory issues...
Thanks

Comment: Why none of the samples start with `a`? any particular reason?

Comment: Is this something for which [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutation#itertools.combinations) could be used?

Comment: @Chris Looking for combinations starting with particular letter from given list. Question Edited. Thanks

Comment: @summea not successful, looking for some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use itertools.permutations() on the string `'aaaabbb'`. It's not "efficient" and you'd need to remove duplicates.

```
from itertools import permutations

for l in set(permutations('a'*4 + 'b'*3, 7)):
    print(*l, sep='')
```

```
babbaaa
abaabba
bbaaaab
aaabbba
ababaab
abaaabb
baaaabb
babaaba
aababba
baaabba
aabbaab
abbbaaa
abbaaba
baababa
bababaa
aabaabb
aaabbab
abaabab
bbabaaa
baaabab
aaaabbb
aabbbaa
bbbaaaa
baabbaa
babaaab
aababab
abbabaa
bbaaaba
abababa
baabaab
aaababb
abbaaab
bbaabaa
ababbaa
aabbaba
```

Generalised into a function:

```
from itertools import permutations

def f(**kwargs):
    population = ''.join(s*n for s,n in kwargs.items())
    return (''.join(l) for l in set(permutations(population, len(population))))

>>> f(a=3, b=4)
<generator object f.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7fc1ec51fd60>

>>> list(f(a=3, b=4))
['aabbabb', 'bbaaabb', 'bbbbaaa', 'aaabbbb', 'bbbaaab', 'abaabbb', 'bbbaaba', 'baabbab', 'babbaab', 'bbabbaa', 'babaabb', 'babbaba', 'baaabbb', 'aabbbab', 'aabbbba', 'baabbba', 'bbaabab', 'baababb', 'bbabaab', 'aababbb', 'abbbbaa', 'bbaabba', 'bbababa', 'abbabab', 'abababb', 'bababab', 'abbabba', 'bababba', 'abbbaab', 'abbbaba', 'abbaabb', 'babbbaa', 'bbbabaa', 'ababbab', 'ababbba']
>>> print(*(f(a=3, b=4)))
aabbabb bbaaabb bbbbaaa aaabbbb bbbaaab abaabbb bbbaaba baabbab babbaab bbabbaa babaabb babbaba baaabbb aabbbab aabbbba baabbba bbaabab baababb bbabaab aababbb abbbbaa bbaabba bbababa abbabab abababb bababab abbabba bababba abbbaab abbbaba abbaabb babbbaa bbbabaa ababbab ababbba

>>> list(f(a=1,b=1,c=1))
['cab', 'bac', 'abc', 'acb', 'bca', 'cba']
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, Here we can only print only combinations starting with 'b' example?

Comment: Remove one of the `b`s and calculate the permutations without it. Then add one `b` back tp the front

Comment: Also, there might be a better way... this one will very quickly become too slow as the sizes increase. To that end you should perhaps remove your acceptance of this answer to encourage other answers. You can accept it later if nothing better comes along.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for permutations, not combinations.  Then you cast it as a set to get rid of identical permutations.

```
import itertools as it

def find_combos(n,a,b):
    lst = ["a"]*a + ["b"]*b
    return set(it.permutations(lst))

for p in find_combos(7,4,3):
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your most effecient method is going to be to use the combination values from a range() as the position values for inserting new characters. Also, utilizing a recursive function, I believe we can write a function to accommodate any size alphabet.

```
from itertools import combinations

letters = 'abcdefghijklmnop'
def combos(*sizes,level=[]):
    a = sum(sizes[len(level):])
    b = sizes[len(level)]
    if a!=b:
        for i in combinations(range(a),b):
            for r in f(*sizes, level=level + [i]):
                yield r
    else:
        r = [letters[len(sizes)-1]]*sizes[-1]
        for l,c in reversed(list(zip(level,letters))):
            for i in l:
                r.insert(i,c)
        yield ''.join(r)

print(list(combos(3,4)))
print(list(combos(2,2)))
print(list(combos(2,1,2)))
```